# Is this a single jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm not that great at jQuery.  That said I found this effect used in a template I wish to duplicate. It has a slide show running in a loop with fly up buttons at the bottom. I was trying to decipher the code but its pretty hard.

Questions:
   Is this just custom code or is there a plugin out there that works like this?
   Is this a combination of plugs?

Any suggestions on which plugin is being used here would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is the example http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_34641/

Answer (score 1):

Try using Nivo slider, I find its easy to use and pretty flexible :)

[http://nivo.dev7studios.com/pricing/][1]

[1]: Nivo Slider

Answer (score 1):

seems to be:

```
$(function(){
    $('.box4').hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".m1").stop().animate({top:-143}, "normal")
    }, function(){
        $(this).find(".m1").stop().animate({top:0}, "normal")
    });
});
```

If I understood the question correct.